# Joining 2 pandas dataframes on a very large number of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

Is it possible to join two pandas dataframes on a very large number of columns in one of the dataframes? I have 15 in this hypothetical example but I would really like to do this for about 100 columns and a lot more rows...

Say you have Dataframe 1:

```
A     Type
123   hi
356   bye
999   nay
222   no
```

Dataframe 2 is:

```
1    2     3    4     5    6   7   8  9  10 11  12   13   14   15....
0    0    123  356   999  999 222  0  0   0  0   0    0    0    0
222  356    0    0     0  356 123 999 0   0  0   0    0    0    0
```

and for the output to be

```
1    2     3    4     5    6   7   8  9  10 11  12   13   14   15

           hi   bye   nay  nay no
no   bye                   bye hi  nay
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC using `replace`

```
df2.replace(df1.set_index('A').T.to_dict('r')[0]).replace(0,'')
Out[830]: 
    1    2   3    4    5    6   7    8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
0           hi  bye  nay  nay  no                         
1  no  bye                bye  hi  nay
```

Or we can using `map`

```
d=df1.set_index('A').T.to_dict('r')[0]
df2.apply(lambda x :x.map(d)).fillna('')
```

Comment: I am trying to run the code now, what is the computational complexity for this? My dataset is 5000 by 100, how much would it take?

Comment: @mkheifetz Personally I do not think speed is problem , you can test the timing and let me know:-)

Comment: for some reason I am getting an error message, not sure how to fix this: TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'

Comment: actually, it seems like the 2nd way worked. Thank you! Also, I was wondering, how can I get in contact with you? I am in the early stages of my data science career as well, love meeting people interested in the same thing...

Comment: @mkheifetz we can get in touch here, and I will get my linkedin profile updated ASAP  :-)

Comment: sounds good, I will add you on Linkedin after you update... Thanks for your help on this question!

Comment: @mkheifetz happy coding my friend :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is cleaner?

```
df2.replace(df1.set_index('A')['Type'].to_dict())
```

Comment: for this one, I got the same error message as the first solution in the other one (however the 2nd solution by Wen worked).

Comment: @mkheifetz Sorry, I cannot reproduce the error... It works on my machine..